# Is there a KiCad library with parts used in retrocomputers?

Tags: hardware, utilities, homemade

I ran into this question a few times and couldn't find any acceptable answer:

Once I was trying to reverse engineer a card that had chips like Intel's 8255 PPI, 8226 bus drivers and some other ICs. I ended up redrawing the needed part of the schematic on a sheet of paper and later forgot about this question.

Now I am slowly working on my homebrew computer project using 8080 CPU and have some further plans for a board with 8086/8087 or 80188 in my head. Once again I can't find some of the components I want to use in any of the libraries on the internet.

Knowing that retro computer builders and various tinkerers have to have some way to draw their schematics, I wonder whether I am bad at searching or does nobody use KiCad for this job?

Comment: Some of the KiCad library searches point to broken sites. Renie Marquet's [Kicad Area](http://www.reniemarquet.com/bibliotecas_en.html "Kicad Area") claims to have a lot of older Intel components. I haven't tested them, so only including this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People *do* use KiCad for this job! The S100 Computers group have created many, many boards using KiCad (included in the list [here](//s100computers.com/My%20System%20Index%20Page.htm#My_System_Index_Table)) and provide the KiCad files used to create each of them. Including the relevant libraries. These will be in 2013 format, but you can convert them to a later format if neccesary.

For 8086 components, [S100 Computers - 8086 CPU Board](//s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/8086%20Board/8086%20CPU%20Board.htm) offers [these KiCad files](//s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/8086%20Board/V1%20S100%208086.zip). I can't see any 8087 or 80118 boards on the list, but many of the components will be the same (I assume).

I couldn't find much else online, save a few tutorials on how to create your own components. If you know enough about the components you need, you could try creating them yourself.

Comment: If you *do* end up making your own components, please share the library with us!

Comment: I found some components at the link scruss posted and I guess I'll end up making the remaining ones myself. I find the component management part of KiCad a bit terrible.

Maybe I should start collecting a library with old parts for reverse engineering and building retro computers... Or is that a little bit pointless?

Comment: @Algimantas Not pointless, no. Did you end up making it?